# Unicode characters not working in kivy python

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, kivy

I want to use unicode symbols for text in buttons, but kivy does'not want to show it.

Like this:

```
self.add_widget(KeyboardButtonOthers(text = u'\u232B', size_hint = (1/7, 0.2)))
#Here I use Sans font
```

Or this:

```
<MainButton@Button>:
    text: '⌂ Exit'
#Here I use default Roboto kivy font
```

In both cases nothing works. Instead normal symbols I getting this:
[Sans font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zamXf.png)

And this:
[Roboto font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqzv8.png)

I work under Windows, but I plan to install the project on Linux. Maybe they will work on Linux and this is a Windows problem?
Thanks for help.

#########################

I found a good solution for my case without using unicode symbols. If you need something like this you can try this:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<KeyboardButtonBackspace@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (166/255, 166/255, 166/255, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (80/255, 80/255, 80/255, 1) 
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [5]
    Image:
        source: 'images/clear2.png'
        size: self.parent.size
        y: self.parent.y
        x: self.parent.x
        allow_stretch: True
    """)
```

Clear2 is vector icon from here https://icons8.com/icons/set/clear

Answer (score 2):

The used fonts probably don't include glyphs for the [U+232B ERASE TO THE LEFT](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/232B) Unicode codepoint - so a failure/fallback glyph is used. In general, it's a good idea to avoid reliance on the existence of specific symbols in a font and rather use an image or an inline SVG - as you've done in your "solution".

Answer (score 0):

Unicode text can only display characters that are available in the font.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: u'\u00A9 ' + chr(97)
        Button:
            text: u'\u00B6 ' + chr(100)
"""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[kivy Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html)